# CardLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm working on a little game where users login. After you have logged in, you will be able to go to the main menu. I am using a CardLayout which is not working. There are a few final Strings containing the panel names. I have been debugging for a while and I know for sure that this piece of code is reached. Any tips are welcome. Thanks!

```
/*
 * showPanel()
 * Method to switch to a different panel
 * @author Rick Slinkman
 */
public void showPanel(String newPanel) 
{
    game.setCurrentPanel(newPanel);
    cardLayout.show(mainpanel, newPanel);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the game variable type ?

Comment: Its of the type "Game" created by myself. It holds the current User and keeps track of a lot of things. Not really relevant in this part.

Comment: *"I know for sure that this piece of code is reached"*  Don't presume that just because this code is 'reached', that it also contains the problem code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that went wrong was that I did not revalidate my JPanel that holds the cards. This was the solution! Thanks to everyone for taking the effort to help me out.

```
/*
 * showPanel()
 * Method to switch to a different panel
 * @author Rick Slinkman
 */
public void showPanel(String newPanel) 
{
        game.setCurrentPanel(newPanel);
    this.cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cardLayout.show(cards, "" + newPanel);
    cards.revalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code does not require a repaint() anywhere if you call this method
Swing will repaint the layout when it will see a change in it, remove the method call repaint.